# Which match was the one where an Asian player in the Premier League scored a goal by running and passing defenders with speed the whole field?

Tags: football, match-identification

Not long ago I saw a compilation where an Asian player scored a goal by running the whole field (from his field to the opposite field, almost box to box), passing defenders mostly with speed in the Premier League (or in some of the English cup). I didn't pay too much attention to know who he was, but since then I've seen another Asian player scoring a goal after dribbling some defenders and I wanted to know if he was the same guy.

Which match was the one where an Asian player in the Premier League (or in one of the English cups) scored a goal by running and passing defenders across the whole field?

Comment: Are you referring to [this goal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SATljljXCY)?

Comment: @F1Krazy yes, that goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a Premier League match between Tottenham and Burnley on 7 December 2019, in which Tottenham player [Son Heung-Min](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_Heung-min) (who is South Korean) sprinted almost the entire length of the pitch, passing several Burnley players, before scoring:

The goal later won the 2020 [FIFA Puskás Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_Pusk%C3%A1s_Award) for the best goal scored anywhere in the world during the 2019-20 season.